# I have error when I run docker in daemon mode

Tags: docker

I try to run docker in daemon mode but get an error

```
#docker -d -b br0
flag provided but not defined: -d
See 'docker --help'.


#service docker status
docker stop/waiting
```

I need this because I use own bridge for docker instance.
Two weeks ago I did not got any problems  like this, but now I can't understand what happen

```
docker -v
Docker version 1.10.0, build 590d5108
uname -a
3.16.0-60-generic #80~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jan 20 13:37:48 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Have you updated your docker version since it last worked?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest not starting the docker daemon by hand, because not least - the flags and options change.

My running 1.9 docker daemon has flags:

```
/usr/bin/docker daemon -H fd://
```

I would suggest what has happened here, is that the docker invocation has changed - it's no longer `docker -d` - it changed between my two installs (1.7.1 and 1.9.1).

If you look at the [`docker daemon`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/daemon/) manpage you'll see the `-d` flag is gone.

But actually, I'd suggest not running it by hand at all, and look at altering the service invocation. On my Centos6 box, that's `/etc/sysconfig/docker` (You can see where this is by reading `/etc/init.d/docker` which is what `service` invokes)

Comment: Thank you for quick response.  But what if I want use bridge **br0**. This bridge have ip addr from my local network and that bridge I create my self.
This command I use to create new bridge and delete docker0 bridge:
`stop docker
stop network-manager 
ip link set dev docker0 down  
brctl delbr docker0
brctl addbr br0
ip addr add 192.19.0.10/24 dev br0
ip link set dev br0 up
brctl addif br0 eth0
ip link set dev eth0 up`

Comment: Edit `/etc/sysconfig/docker` to include the `-b` flag. Or consider using `docker network` instead.